# How to iterate through Array of Hashes in a Hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have an Array of Hashes in a Hash that looks like this:

```
$var  = {
      'items' => [
                      {
                        'name'  => 'name1',
                        'type'  => 'type1',
                        'width' => 'width1',
                      },
                      {
                        'name'  => 'name2',
                        'type'  => 'type2',
                        'width' => 'width2',
                      },
                      {
                        'name'  => 'name3',
                        'type'  => 'type3',
                        'width' => 'width3',
                      }                      
                   ]
    };
```

I wrote the following code to get the values from a file.

```
my @members = ("name"    =>  $name,
               "type"    =>  $type,
               "width"   =>  $width);

$rec->{$items} = [ @members ];

push @var, $rec;
```

I am not sure how to retrieve the values from this data structure.

I saw the solution in [Iterate through Array of Hashes in a Hash in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155607/iterate-through-array-of-hashes-in-a-hash-in-perl/12155656#12155656). 
But I did not understand it. I am not sure what was $filelist that they had mentioned in the code.

```
foreach my $file (@{ $filelist{file} }) {
    print "path: $file->{pathname}; size: $file->{size}; ...\n";
}
```

I am new to perl and please provide me details in your reply.

Comment: `$var` is a reference to a hash, and one of the elements of that hash (the only one so far) is the `items` array. Do you need to have any other elements besides `items` in that hash?

Answer (score 3):

An excellent reference for data structures like the one you're dealing with is [Perl's Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

That said, here is the code:

```
for my $item (@{$aoh->{items}}) {
    # '@' casts the $aoh->{items} hash references to an array
    print $item->{name};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the structure in that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155607/iterate-through-array-of-hashes-in-a-hash-in-perl/12155656#12155656) like

```
$VAR1 = {
          'file' => [
                      {
                        'pathname' => './out.log',
                        'size' => '51',
                        'name' => 'out.log',
                        'time' => '1345799296'
                      },
.
.
.
}
```

is actually print or output of the hashref `$filelist`. `Data::Dumper` module which helps in printing the structures like hashref, arrayref, etc. in a way that you can read properly.

So `$VAR1` is nothing but `$filelist` printed using Dumper.

Now, about the foreach loop iterating through values:

```
foreach my $file (@{ $filelist{file} })
```

Here, the `$filelist{file}` part returns the array reference (Note: `[`, `]` represents arrayref).

Now, when you use `@{}` on this arrayref i.e. `@{ $filelist{file} }`, this converts or expands as array.

Once we get the arrayref converted to array type, we can iterate using `foreach`.

Please note that when you use `$hashrefname->{$key}`, it means hashref accessing the key, 
`$hashname{$key}` means hash accessing key. Same is for arrayef and array, but instead of keys there are numbers to acess in case of array.

**Solution for your problem:**

You need to store the members as hashref and not array i.e.

```
my $member = {"name"    =>  $name,
               "type"    =>  $type,
               "width"   =>  $width};
```

Then you can push this each hashref that you read from file(i am guessing it is from file)
into the array

```
push @arr, $member
```

And then assign the arrayref to the items

```
$rec->{items} = \@arr
```

Now you can access values as

```
foreach my $eachhashref (@{$rec->{items}})
{
print $eachhashref->{name}
}
```