# Iterating over an array of hashes inside of a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, hash

I am new to Perl and I am having a hard time with iterating over an array of hashes inside of a hash. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124033/how-to-iterate-through-array-of-hashes-in-a-hash-in-perl)Here is the data structure from Dumper:

```
1234 => {  
        'items' => [
            #0 { 
                    'k1' => { 'x1' => '123', 'x2' => '321' }, 
                    'k2' => 'v2', 
                    'k3' => 'v3', 
                    'k4' => 'v4' 
                }, 
            #1 { 
                    'k1' => { 'x1' => '123', 'x2' => '321' }, 
                    'k2' => 'v2', 
                    'k3' => 'v3', 
                    'k4' => 'v4' 
                }, 
            #2 { 
                    'k1' => { 'x1' => '123', 'x2' => '321' }, 
                    'k2' => 'v2', 
                    'k3' => 'v3', 
                    'k4' => 'v4' 
                },
            ],
}
```

Here is the code I have. I want to iterate over the hash '%myHash' while having access to both the keys and values. Then for each hash inside the "items" array I want to perform some operation.

In this case, my key is '1234' and its value is a hash that contains the key 'items'. This is the code I have (a ref to the hash is being passed to my sub):

```
sub iterateHash {
    my %myHash = @_;

    while (my ($key, $value) = each %myHash) {
        my %newHash;
        foreach my $item (@{ $value->{'items'} }) {
            if( !(defined $newHash{'nk1'}) ) {
                $newHash{'nk1'} = $item{'k1'}{'x2'};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and how it is called:

```
my $results = iterateHash(\%myHash);
```

I have uses for the key later on which is why I want access to both the key and value in a pair in the outer while loop, but for now I want to get this part working.

This is the error I get:

```
Global symbol "%item" requires explicit package name
```

Comment: Please show how this was invoked, including how the argument to `iterateHash` was defined.  Did you pass an actual hash or a hash reference?  Once you get into nested structures, _everything_ is a reference.

Comment: @JimGarrison I mentioned above I am passing a reference to this sub. Added the call above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed a reference but didn't treat it like a reference inside `iterateHash`.  Also, once you get into nested structures, everything is a reference, so `$item` is a hash *reference* not a  plain hash.

```
sub iterateHash {
    my ($myHash) = @_;

    while (my ($key, $value) = each %$myHash) {
        my %newHash;
        foreach my $item (@{ $value->{'items'} }) {
            if( !(defined $newHash{'nk1'}) ) {
                $newHash{'nk1'} = $item->{'k1'}->{'x2'};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah ok. so I wasn't dereferencing the hash I passed in to access the values or the nested item? thanks

Comment: That is correct.  I personally find it much easier to work with references everywhere, since that's what you work with inside nested data structures. I never (well almost never) use plain hashes.

Comment: if I use '%$myHash', it gives this error: "Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs".

Comment: Oops... minor mistake in my code, I'll fix it.  Forgot the parentheses around `$myHash` in the first statement.

Comment: Thanks - what do the parentheses around $myHash in the sub do?

Comment: Provide list context so the first element of `@_` is assigned to `$myHash`