# perl: Print object property names and values

Tags: perl

The following:

```
for my $z (@$y) {                               
  # prints number of observables for a given activity summary
  # print STDERR 'property count'.keys $z
  print Dumper($z);
}
```

Prints:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'activity' => 'walking',
          'duration' => '591',
          'calories' => 26,
          'distance' => '435',
          'steps' => 871,
          'group' => 'walking'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'steps' => 168,
          'group' => 'walking',
          'distance' => '100',
          'activity' => 'walking',
          'duration' => '200',
          'calories' => 6
        };
```

How can I iterate over each property and print its name and value? Im using perl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through Array of Hashes in a Hash in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155607/iterate-through-array-of-hashes-in-a-hash-in-perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
for my $z (@$y) {
    for my $k (keys %$z) {
        print "$k: $z->{$k}\n";
    }
}
```

See [`perldoc -f keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) for more information about `keys`; [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for general information about hashes (because your `$z` values are hash references, not objects); [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for references and nested data structures.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
my $z = {
      'activity' => 'walking',
      'duration' => '591',
      'calories' => 26,
      'distance' => '435',
      'steps' => 871,
      'group' => 'walking'
    };


while((my $key, my $value) = each (%{$z})){
    print "key : $key -> value : $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Using `each` is generally not recommended because it uses iterator state stored in the hash itself. This can lead to weird action-at-a-distance bugs.